# Install older version of gcc for Fedora?

Tags: gcc, fedora

What is the difficulty in providing an easy way to downgrade gcc 6 to version 4?

I have a project that seems not forward-compatible with gcc. Therefore I'm trying to downgrade gcc to v4 but it is impossible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maintenance of each piece of software in the distribution takes some efforts. Especially in cases, when there is some security vulnerability that needs to be fixed and you have many parallel versions. There is no reason to keep old versions, if there is nobody using inside of the distribution.

Currently there is GCC 7 in Fedora 26, so GCC 4 is three major versions behind. If your application does not attempt to keep up with the GCC, Fedora is not an OS for you, because it moves forward. If you strive for backward compatibility, you should consider using RHEL/CentOS 7, where is still GCC 4 and it will be supported for years.

Comment: I'll try with CentOS then! Thanks